# rewirite bootstap dropdown for angular 8

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I have many dropdowns bootstrap on project,the bootstrap require jquery.I want to cut out jquery and bootstrap. Can i replace bootstrap dropdown on angular material dorpdown? Or is there a better way?tell me any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-bootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples). It not use jquery. 
I think, rewrite html from bootstrap to material is very tiring and long task (but not hard). This is your decision.

Extra info: if you use Angular 8 and update to angular 9, you have to update material 8 to material 9 (because of slider not work properly, etc.).

Material 9 has some new, for example: if you use a material module, you have to import it. In previous version you can import easily from one directory:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material'
```

but now in version 9, you have to rewrite all import, because of modules are in separate directory. 
Now you can import like this:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'.
```

Just imagine that, if you import many modules in many files and after material update you have to rewrite all import then your brain explodes and you are looking for another specialty.

I hope that i can help you.

Comment: can i install only angular bootstrap dropdown without install all ng-bootstrap?

Comment: Unfortunately you can not do it. BUT use ngx-bootstrap instead of ng-bootstrap. 

In ngx-bootstrap you can download that package what you want to use: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns